# GNU Parallel to process multiple files in parallel in Unix with bash

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, gnu-parallel

I have a bash script I am using to iterate over a list of files and search for regex matches. Here is a snippet from my current code:

`for file in $Files_To_Parse; do
    (cat $file) | grep -ioE "($Keys$Delimiters$Payload+$End_String)" | grep -v 'null' | grep -v '*'
done`

- $Files_To_Parse is a string of space separated file names
- $Keys, $Delimiters, $Payload$, and End_String are regex patterns.

This code currently works (slowly).

I would like to either have multiple files processed in parallel, or one file which regex matches are searched for in parallel; however, I am not sure how to use GNU's Parallel package to accomplish this.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Simplify a lot of it with `grep -h pattern "$Files_To_Parse"` - that'll at least give grep several files to look at at a time, instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that your disks I/O might be limiting you:

```
doit() {
    (cat "$1") | grep -ioE "($Keys$Delimiters$Payload+$End_String)" | grep -v 'null' | grep -v '*'
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: $Files_To_Parse
```

Consider walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it:

```
man parallel_tutorial
```

Comment: Vastly under-rated answer. In the modern era of plentiful cores and plentiful I/O, especially when inputs don't need to be in a specific order, parallel *demolishes* these workloads. Kudos to you, Ole - you've built something amazing.